# Syntax of a multi-row update that updates specific rows with unique information

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I've been having a hard time finding a good example of exactly what I am trying to do.

I have a multidimensional array containing 1-N entries. I want to update a table in MySQL from this array, but I want to update all the rows in a single query. I wasn't able to find any examples of a multi-row update that set the values for multiple columns and also had where clause like functionality to determine which rows were updated.

The table I am working with is setup like this:

```
TABLE
name varchar,
quota int,
warehouse int,
production int,
missing int
```

The array is ordered like this, TABLE.name corresponds to Material Name:

```
$list = array(
    'Material Name One'=>array(1000,200,600,200),
    'Material Name Two'=>array(5000,0,4500,500)
);
```

Could someone please provide an example of how to form this type of syntax?

I want to use a single update as the size of the array/table may eventually grow quite large and I'm under the impression that this method is better than making hundreds of small updates in quick succession.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I don't see what is wrong with separately executed updates especially with prepared statements.

But if you want for any reason to implement a multi row update you will need to build a query like this

```
UPDATE Table1 t JOIN
(
    SELECT 'Material Name One' name, 1000 quota, 200 warehouse, 600 production, 200 missing
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Material Name Two', 5000, 0, 4500, 500
    -- You can add extra rows here
    -- with UNION ALL
) u ON t.name = u.name
   SET t.quota = u.quota,
       t.warehouse = u.warehouse,
       t.production = u.production,
       t.missing = u.missing;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7d42/1)** example.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting the syntax for this to be much more complicated, but it seems pretty straight forward. I will read up on prepared statements, currently I just build the query as a string and I know that's not efficient.

Comment: After a little more research it would seem a prepared statement would be easy to retrofit into my project. Thanks for taking the time to write that up and provide an SQLFiddle example, that is a really neat tool.